Equivalent condition to $U$ being simply connected
From an old qualifying exam, I was asked to show that for $U$ a connected open set, the following are equivalent:

$U$ is simply connected
for all holomorphic $f, g : U \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $f^2 + g^2 = 1$, there is a holomorphic $h : U \to \mathbb{C}$ such that
$$f = \cos h, g = \sin h$$

I was able to show one direction assuming that $U$ is simply connected, but I cannot seem to get the reverse direction. I think this direction is probably easier, but I might need a hint.

By standard theorems (which should be covered in an introductory complex analysis class) it is enough to show that any nonvanishing holomorphic $q$ on $U$ has a holomorphic logarithmic; solving $q=f+ig$ and $1/q=f-ig$ (noting that $f^2+g^2=1$ and $f,g$ are linear combinations of $q,1/q$) in terms of the $h$ above should give you that $q=e^h$

Actually in the above it should be $q=e^{ih}$ but that of course is fine also - to prove that the statement above with logarithm implies simply connected, wlog we can assume $U$ not the whole plane and then one shows that $U$ is conformally equivalent to a bounded domain (using the existence of a square root for nonvanishing functions) and then if there is a bounded component of the complement, $z-w$ has no logarithm on $U$ for any $w$ in that

@Conrad thank you for the hint. I have solved it; my main issue was finding the proper $f, g$, but after reading your comment, it suddenly became clear.

Excellent - happy to be of help

@MathLearner12 Then you should write an answer to your own question.
